# Enabling primefaces selectOneRadio with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

The title is self explanatory, I want enable/disable the p:selectOneRadio using javascript.
I've tryied widget.enable(), widget.disable(), widget.disabled(false) but still can't find any method in widgetVar that help do this.
I've looked at primefaces source but can't find selectOneRadio in javascript lib.

Comment: This component has no client side Api in primefaces user manual 3.5. Can you give more details of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: maybe you can use other way...

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces widget has no API method for this, so you'd need to set `disabled` attribute on HTML elements.

Assuming your radio has id "radio":

```
var radio = $('[id$=radio] input')
radio.attr('disabled','disabled')
```

Comment: Functionality added on 19.01.2016 for `5.3.6` and `5.2.19`. see: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1042